# RestTemplate don't return value with Snake Case in Spring REST

Tags: json, resttemplate, camelcasing

I have REST API with property in application.properties as below:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy: CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
```

Everything is OK! But when I use RestTemplate to do as below, but I found all key in Snake Case is null (ex. nameEnglish), but regular key name are ok (ex. rank), how can I solve this problem?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id"})
@Entity
public class Brand implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9165709510160554127L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private String nameChinese;
    private String nameEnglish;
    private String rank;
}
```

I saved a data as below:

```
Saved Brand: Brand(id=1, version=1, nameChinese=乐高, nameEnglish=Lego, rank=Top)
```

But when I try code as below:

```
Brand brands = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/brand/lego", Brand.class);
System.out.println(brands);
```

The result as below, you will see all Camel Case properties in null, though I set value to them:

```
Saved Brand: Brand(id=1, version=1, nameChinese=null, nameEnglish=null, rank=Top)
```

The Json format result form CocoaRestCLient

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "country_chinese": "芬兰",
    "version": 1,
    "homepage_url": "http://www.lego.com",
    "country_english": "Finland",
    "name_english": "Lego",
    "rank": "Top",
    "name_chinese": "乐高"
}
```

Comment: Post an example JSON object please.

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: Thanks, it will help. But can you PLS also add an example JSON payload. To avoid missunderstanding.

Comment: This answer is a good fit for this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/40783304/3122912

Answer (score 6):

I think you have a typo in `application.properties`. Correct value is either:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
```

or

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy
```

See [Appendix A. Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) from Spring Boot Reference Guide:

> spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy= # One of the constants on
>   Jackson's PropertyNamingStrategy. Can also be a fully-qualified class
>   name of a PropertyNamingStrategy subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am not sure how to combine your code with mine, I got Brand entity from RestTemplate as Brand brands = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/brand/lego", Brand.class); then your code convert String to Brand...

Comment: The key message is that you change your naming strategy to ' CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES'. That will do.

Comment: What do you mean? I am using spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy: CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES in application.properties.

Comment: Right, I am sorry - I have got confused. I will see to it.

Comment: though the ":" is the same as the "=" in application.properties, I tried your suggestion, no any change, it is still null!

Comment: Hmmm, what about your setters? Are they public, do they have a correct name? E.g: `public void setNameChinese(String name)`, `public void setNameEnglish(String name)`, …

Comment: I use Lombok @Data, they don't have any problems! Or my entity can't be access!

Comment: Can you post example JSON data? Just to be sure, cause you did not confirm my assumption in original version of my answer.

Comment: I modified my question, you can check it.

Comment: `Saved Brand: Brand(id=1, version=1, nameChinese=乐高, nameEnglish=Lego, rank=Top)` is not in JSON format. Can you post your data in JSON format?

Comment: Thank you. Hmmm, I do not see any apparent problem there.

Comment: If you do not receive exception at deserialization I figure out all fields are set, which is strange if you do not have `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation in Brand class. I think I am finished, but I am curious what it is. Good luck.

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same problem here @mikezang, have you figured it out ? I've tried both suggested annotations for application.properties

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check that `RestTemplate` is using the objectMapper provided by spring. In my case I added this and it worked.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HTTPConfig {
    public final ObjectMapper objectMapper;  // provided by spring

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .messageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper))
            .build();
    }
}
```

Assuming you already have `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` in `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the following in `application.properties` worked:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```